# PyQt4 installed correctly but not work

Tags: python, pyqt4

i have python 2.7 on windows 64 bit
also add PyQt4 to python\
start to add code like that:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


class HelloWorld(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        label = QLabel("Hello world")
        line_edit = QLineEdit()
        button = QPushButton("close")

        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

i never  see my code achieved neither blank window with blank title!!

Comment: If the above code is complete: you're only defining a class. You're neither starting a `QApplication` as you have to nor are you actually creating or showing an instance of your `HelloWorld` class - so, if you're not getting any errors, everything seems fine...

Answer (score 1):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class HelloWorld(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        label = QtGui.QLabel("Hello world")
        line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("close")

        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

so far, so good.
For testing your code by pressing F5 add:

```
def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    hw = HelloWorld()
    hw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and:

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

and i suggest to start here: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/